# Best practice: should I use an AR Model or a global Hash for static data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm thinking about a social networking-site. My user-model should have an attribute "eyecolor", which could be set on a view-page with a select-box/dropdownlist.

My question:
-> should I make a AR-Model or should I use a global Hash/Constant for the data?
Is there a best practice for "static-models"?

And how do I associate following without an AR-Model with relations:

```
u = User.first 
u.eyecolor 
==> 1 (not the eyecolor-string!)
```

What I need is the eyecolor-string:

```
u = User.first 
u.eyecolor 
==> "brown"
```

Thanks,
sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a model to handle your eye-color logic:

```
class EyeColor
   COLORS = ['blue','brown','hazel']

   attr_accessor :color

   # Some logic methods...
   def is_brown?
     self.color == 'brown'
   end

end
```

Note:  this model is not an Active Record model, but it does create an abstraction the real-world object you are trying to model.

EDIT:  I also like this approach as opposed to a global hash, because it gives it organizes your static definition within EyeColor instead of floating around in your program, which makes it clear where this definition is.

```
<%= select :user, :eye_color, EyeColor::COLORS %>
```

EDIT: added question mark to predicate method.

Comment: The other nice thing about this particular approach is you get an opportunity to move on if you find the abstraction becomes greater than a simple lookup.  Essentially the refactor becomes a matter of adding a couple of methods or making the class inherit from AR.

Comment: I really like this idea but am having trouble coming up with code that works for me.  In my site I want to allow the admin to change the name of the site (SITE_NAME) and store it in the DB.  However, I think its overkill to retrieve SITE_NAME every time I need to display a page.  Could you give a bit more detail on the "Some logic methods..." section of your answer?  :)

Thanx!
  Richard

Comment: http://pastie.org/482993

I've mocked up some code here.  Does this look workable or am I traveling down the wrong road?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a Constant. I put these in a file in config/initializers/constants.rb; that way they are all in the same place.

```
EyeColors = %w{Blue Brown Hazel Green}
```

In your form just do:

```
<%= f.select :eye_color, EyeColors %>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have some data, you should put it in the database. This doesn't mean you have to load it each time you use it:

```
class EyeColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  def self.allowed_eye_colors
    @@eye_colors ||= AllowedEyeColor.find(:all)
  end
end
```

You access this as `EyeColor.allowed_eye_colors`. It's loaded the first time you use it, and then cached in the class variable.

Comment: Gave an up-vote for this a year later.  I like it better than my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check into [constant_cache](https://github.com/tpitale/constant_cache). Storing this info in the DB, but having it cached lets you add/remove constants (in the db) without changing your actual code.